# On 2d manifolds, is Ricci the only (intrinsic) symmetric 2-tensor which is derivative of metric up to 2nd order?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

By "intrinsic", I mean, something which doesn't depend choice of coordinates.

I think this is true, but is this actually a **theorem** that is written in some book?

Is there some sort of "classification theorem" of this type in higher dimensions?

Comment: Note that if we know it comes from the curvature, then, we have decomposition theorems as in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295309/are-the-ricci-and-scalar-curvatures-the-only-interesting-tensors-coming-from-t      But, why does it have to come from curvature...?

Comment: [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214433166) might be of some interest.