# Which coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of the shape operator are isometric invariants?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be an isometrically immersed Riemannian hypersurface.  The *shape operator* $s$ is the $(1,1)$ tensor field characterized by
$$\langle X, sY \rangle = \langle \text{II}(X,Y), N\rangle,$$
where $X$, $Y$ are vector fields, $\text{II}$ is the second fundamental form, and $N$ is a unit normal vector field.  We can then define the *mean curvature* and *Gaussian curvature* by
$$H = \frac{1}{n}\text{tr}(s), \ \ \ \ \ \ K = \det(s).$$

Gauss' [Theorema Egregium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium) is the statement that $K$ is an isometry invariant of $M$ **when $\mathbf{n = 2}$**.  By contrast, $H$ is not.  This makes me wonder about the following:

> **Question:** Let $p(\lambda) = \lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ denote the characteristic polynomial of the shape operator $s$.  For $n > 2$, are any of the coefficients $a_i$ (local) isometry invariants of $M$?  If so, which?

Again, a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/are-there-higher-dimensional-analogues-of-sectional-curvature) of mine was meant to get at this, but my thoughts were not quite so clear.

Comment: I'm not sure that the gaussian curvature is an isometry invariant for an hypersurface of arbitrary dimension $ n $. Are you sure about it? If  $ n=2 $ we know that the gaussian curvature is an isometry invariant because it is equal to the sectional curvature of $ M $ (note in this case the sectional curvature is merely a function on $ M $).

Comment: @user55449: Wow, I hadn't realized that at all. Thank you for clarifying; that's a really good point.  Hm, I'm not quite sure how to salvage this question.  Oh, well.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question accordingly, though it's somewhat more pessimistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n>2$ then all the coefficients $a_m$ are isometry invariants of generic $M$.
Say, it sufficient to assume that $M$ has positive curvature, but as you will see much weaker assumptions can be made.

Let $e_i$ be the principle basis and $\kappa_i$ be principle curvatures.
The curvature operator of $M$ has eigenvectors $e_i\wedge e_j$ with eigenvalues $K_{ij}=\kappa_i\cdot\kappa_j$.
If $K_{ij}>0$ and $n>2$, you can recover $\kappa_i$ from $K_{ij}$,
say
$$\kappa_i=\sqrt{\frac{K_{ij}\cdot K_{ik}}{K_{jk}}}.$$
Since the values $K_{ij}$ are isometry invariants of $M$
so are all $\kappa_i$ and symmetrizing we get all $a_m$ (up to sign).

About other conditions:
say nonzero Gaussian curvature $G=\kappa_1\cdots\kappa_n$
will do as well and the proof is the same.
In particular $|G|$ is invariant.

On the other hand for the hyperplane $|H|=\mathrm{const}\cdot |a_1|$ is not invariant, so you should assume something about curvature at the point.

Comment: Interesting. Can you clarify some things for me?  Perhaps in an edit? (1) Are you saying that the $\kappa_i$ are _intrinsic_ isometry invariants of generic $M$ when $n > 2$? (2) What specific operator do you mean by "curvature operator of $M$"? (3) I thought negative curvature was in some sense more generic than positive curvature?

Comment: @Jesse: (1) Yes in generic case, say if $G\ne 0$; (2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_of_Riemannian_manifolds (3) Well, if $n>2$, negatively curved mnfld can not be isometric to hypersurface...

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Do you have any references for (3)? My differential geometry education has consisted of classical surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and abstract Riemannian manifolds, with virtually no bridge in between. In particular, I know almost nothing (as you can see) about how the geometry of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generalizes (or not) to hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I don't have a reference for (3), but I think I see the reason: write the 3-dimensional hypersurface locally as$$x_4=\sum_{i,j=1}^3 a_{ij} x_ix_j+o(|x|^2)$$ and observe that whatever signature the form $(a_{ij})$ has, it is either positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite on some two-dimensional subspace. Therefore, a hypersurface cannot have negative sectional curvature.

Answer (score 2):

A reference for a fairly general statement is Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry," Volume IV, Section 7D.  I'll just quote the results here.

Let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be an isometrically immersed hypersurface.  Let $\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_n$ be the principal curvatures.  Define the **symmetric curvatures** $K_j$ by
$$K_j = \binom{n}{j}^{-1}\sigma_j(\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_n),$$
where $\sigma_j$ is the $j$th elementary symmetric polynomial.  In particular,
\begin{align*}
H = K_1 & = \textstyle \frac{1}{n}(\kappa_1 + \cdots + \kappa_n) \\
K = K_n & = \kappa_1 \cdots \kappa_n.
\end{align*}
are the mean and Gauss-Kronecker curvatures, respectively.

**Prop:** The set of the $\binom{n}{2}$ numbers $\{\kappa_i \kappa_j \colon i < j\}$ is invariant under isometry.  In particular, the *even* symmetric curvatures $K_{2r}$ are invariant under isometry.

According to Spivak, the "in particular" follows from the algebraic fact that the even powers of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ can be expressed in terms of the determinants of the $2 \times 2$ submatrices of $A$.