# Invariants of shape operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $S:V\longrightarrow V$ be a Linear Transformation, then the Characteristic polynomial of $S$ and therefore its Coefficient are invariant. Except the first and the last Coefficient that we know their meaning, are the remains have geometric meaning?

Comment: Yes, but the meanings are much, much more complicated. If I remember right, this was an open question in algebraic geometry until very recently. Perhaps it still is open. I don't remember.

Comment: This is an interesting question but sadly it is stated in a very poor language, and it is hard to parse what it really asks for. There is an excellent [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/318432/2002) with nearly the same content and a brilliant [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2557/2002) to it.

Comment: Dear Yuri Vyatkin, you right dude, I'm not from english language countries and I'm not smooth in English.